# Image displaying

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, image-processing

I am beginner for using Qt creator to make User Interface, here got some problems.

[image]

This is the basic frame that I designed. As you can see the function is that I can push "select folder" button to select the picture and display it. Now the question is that how can I use the 3 below push button to change the directory without opening the file window.which means I can use the order to do that.

Secondly, I want to ask how I can create a table which contains multiple images and can display them one by one, like got how many columns and how many rows and put them all in an XY axis.
So sorry to ask these question but I have not enough time and no choice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: I assume you are trying to play videos, right? For that you need the list of videos in a given folder.

You can use something like this:

```
QStringList ClassName::ListVideoFilesInDir(const QString &dirPath) const
{
    QDir dir(dirPath);
    QStringList filters;
    filters << "*.mp4"; // or specify more file fomrats by adding << "*.wmv"
    dir.setNameFilters(filters);
    return dir.entryList();
}
```

You should probably take a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html

Now you can take the list of videos (that the above mentioned function returned) and add them to the QMediaPlaylist

```
playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
for(const auto& line : list) {
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl(line));
}
```

Then I would use the push buttons to iterate through this list and select the element to display. Something like this:

```
void Launcher::on_nextButton_clicked()
{
    indexToPlay++;
    playlist->setCurrentIndex(indexToPlay);
    player->play();
}
```

Unfortunately I don't really understand the second part of your question.

Hope this helps though.

Comment: Thanks to helping me, actually there are not videos but a lots of images, because every folder contains a lots of images that why I call it video.So I want to press the pushbutton and change the folder by order and display the path, this for the question one.

Comment: For second question I have already understand I need using opencv to combine multiple images.

Comment: Hmmm. So if I'm correct, then you want to have a list of Paths (of Folders), and you want to be able to change these by button click? So you have a "main" folder with lots of subfolders, right? Like subfolder1, subfolder2 ... subfolderN. And you want to change the current selected folder, by pressing the button?

Comment: In this case I would get the list of folders contained in main.
For this you can use the QDir's entry list function. 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#entryList
If you are only interested in the Folders then pass the following filter:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#Filter-enum

Comment: QStringList listOfSubfolders = QDir(mainFolderPath)
                          .entryList(QDir::AllDirs, QDir::SortFlag::Name)) using this function you get the list :-) If it helped, please mark my answer accepted. Thanks! If not, clarify the problem and I'll help